# chat web app that allows sending messages

Tags: python, flask

I am learning Flask and I want to practice by making simple web app.

I want to make a chat web app that allows sending messages between two or more web browsers in Flask but I am not sure where to start or go about building this application. This question is pretty broad but what I want to know is how to structure this application. What are the pieces I need to build this application.

Comment: Flask and Python is pretty decent start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

very broad question, but I'd recommend starting here with web sockets http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent . Then you can have two member subscribe to a channel and make messages to each other.